# Screen Resolution on Android Unity3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

i have set custom manifest for my android game in unity
in manifest i use

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="false" android:normalScreens="false" 
  android:smallScreens="false" android:resizeable="false" android:anyDensity="false" />
```

for disable streching my game to screen size.because when do strech or scaling to output size, the game is going to slow.
after disable strech my screen like this : 
[image]
my target is android device that show out put on tv
i have the resolution : 1280 * 720
how can i set the camera or resolution or any thing else,to become my screen fit
i use unity 3.5.x
tnx 4 adv
and sorry 4 bad english

Comment: Are you sure you are not doing premature optimization? Filling the entire screen is unlikely to be a performance bottleneck unless you have a lot of transparent/translucent objects in your game (or a few that take up a lot of screen space). That manifest line will prevent your game from showing up on the store if you put it on Google Play or the Amazon App store.

Comment: the game is simple. there is texture on back.camera move upside(+y)
and one AirPlane that can move around the screen,what is premature optimization!?
the game work correct on phone

Comment: Premature optimization is trying to improve your game's performance before you know if there is even a problem. If it's going to run at 60fps fullscreen anyway, then there's no reason to try to do what you're doing.